# tkinter gui crashes after pressing button

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a small GTA San andreas menu that gives you a lot of money with tkinter and python, but whenver i press the button to give me money, the gui crashes but i get the money

heres my code:

```
from ReadWriteMemory import ReadWriteMemory
from tkinter import *

rwm = ReadWriteMemory

process = rwm().get_process_by_name(process_name="gta-sa.exe")
process.open()

# Money

baseaddress = 0x1F0000 + 0x118FD8

moneypointer = process.get_pointer(baseaddress, offsets=[0xB8]) 


def moneygive():
    while 1:
        process.write(moneypointer, 99999999999)

root = Tk()
root.title("GTA San Andreas Menu")
root.iconbitmap()
root.geometry("200x200")

MoneyButton = Button(root, text="Inf money!", padx=50, command=moneygive)
MoneyButton.pack()




root.mainloop()
```

also whenever i try to press the stop button, this error comes

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\####\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\####\PycharmProjects\gtasa\main.py", line 17, in moneygive
    process.write(moneypointer, 99999999999)
  File "C:\Users\####\PycharmProjects\gtasa\venv\lib\site-packages\ReadWriteMemory\__init__.py", line 125, in write
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.WriteProcessMemory(self.handle, lp_base_address, lp_buffer,
```

Comment: The GUI crashes because of the `while` loop, instead of doing it indefinitely, do it once or add a button to break/get off the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use after method of tkinter to create the loop.
While loop will not work inside mainloop. Thanks!